# После установки Debian “squeeze” пропал режим выбора загрузки Windows 7

Tags: windows, debian, grub, dual-boot

День добрый, сегодня поставил Debian и после установки пропало меню выбора загрузки Windows 7. На диске видно диски с ntfs, но как теперь вернуть возможность выбора?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда update-grub